# .NET Core 5 Table Per Type Inheritance Includes

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to retrieve data using a Table Per Type Inheritance strategy. I have a table "Teams" extending table "Groups", where Groups has a link  to the "Tenant" table. When I try to do:

```
var org = await _context.Tenant.Include(t => t.Teams)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == tenantId);
```

I cannot return teams.

My models for teams and groups looks like the following:

```
    [Table("Groups")]
    public class Group
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<GroupUser> GroupUsers { get; set; }

        public int? TenantId { get; set; }
        public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    }


    [Table("Teams")]
    public class Team : Group
    {
        public string TeamManagerId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser TeamManager { get; set; }
    }
```

In the context I have this for the group:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Group>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(x => x.Tenant)
                    .WithMany(t => t.Clusters)
                    .HasForeignKey(x => x.TenantId)
                    .IsRequired(false)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);  
            });
```

Then teams returns nothing, bit if I change Teams to Groups (in the query) it works, as one would expect. I realise this may be to do with the join setup for groups as above in the context, but not sure what to put if anything for teams, as it has no direct link to the tenant table, it's join is supposed to be via Groups.

How do I return teams?

Many Thanks

Eamon

Comment: *both belong to the "Tenant" table* - this describes it wrong, you should use correct words to talk about relationships between entities. To make it clear, you should include detailed entity classes, write the working query and non-working query separately ... We don't usually like to guess the things although in some cases we may be able to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the group and it's child model team?

You should add relationship **between team and tenant**, not group and tenant.

Check my demo:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }          
}

public class Team : Group
{
    public string TeamManagerId { get; set; }
    public int? TenantId { get; set; }
    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}

public class Tenant
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

Then the linq；

```
var model = _context.Tenants.Include(x => x.Teams).ToList();
```

To use:

```
@model IEnumerable<Tenant>

@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
     foreach (var item2 in item.Teams)
    {
        @item2.Name; //group property
        @item2.TeamManagerId; //team property
    }
 }
```